# size_t and unsigned int does not match in a template function's parameter list

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use  a stack to store indices of an array,so I use the following typedef,where istack is a template class for stack:

```
typedef istack<size_t> IndexStack;
```

and I declare a stack by

```
IndexStack    stack;
```

But when I call the following function (where A.size() returns a size_t);

```
stack.push_back(A.size());
```

GCC gives the following error

> `sort.cpp: In function 'void quicksort2(Array&)':`
>    `sort.cpp:50:27: error: no matching function for call to 'istack<unsigned int>::push_back(size_t)'`
>    `iarray.h:103:8: note: candidate is: void istack<T>::push_back(T&) [with T = unsigned int]`

How can I make it work?

Comment: what type does your push_back takes as argument?

Comment: Does `push_back` perhaps take a non-const reference? I think the issue is rather that you can't pass temporaries in such case.

Comment: Stop trying to explain your code in English (it is not an exact language). Just put the exact code into the question (we can all read code quite well). Reserve your English explanation for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <cstddef>
template <class T>
struct istack
{
    void push_back(T& value);
    std::size_t size() const;
};

int main()
{
    typedef istack<size_t> IndexStack;
    IndexStack    a, stack;
    stack.push_back(a.size());
}
```

This code produces an error

```
In function 'int main()':
13 no matching function for call to 'istack<unsigned int>::push_back(size_t)'
note 5 candidates are: void istack<T>::push_back(T&) [with T = unsigned int]
```

Note that it lists candidates. (I suspect you are not reading / posting the entire error message.)

The given candidate doesn't match the call, because the reference is non-const. A temporary (such as the result of `a.size()`) cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

`push_back` should be taking a `const T& value`

Comment: That's the problem.push_back doesn't take const reference.By the way I forget to paste the third line of error message.Thanks very much for your answer.